# Can set mouseover html attribute by javascript, but cannot assign function to mouseover property in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

Clearly I'm doing something stupid.

```
    processTextNodes: function processTextNodes(node) { 
    node = node || content.document.body;                    // base node 
    var children = node.childNodes, i = 0;

    while (node = children[i]) { 
        if (node.nodeType == 3 && node.textContent) {        // text node found, replace enclosed text.
            if (node.nodeName == "script") continue;

            /*node.parentNode.setAttribute("onmouseover", "alert(\"AAA\");");*/
            node.parentNode.onmouseover = function(){ alert("AAA") };
            node.textContent = aatel.transliterate(node.textContent);
        }
        if (node.nodeType == 1) {
            if (node.title) node.title = aatel.transliterate(node.title);
            if (node.alt)   node.alt = aatel.transliterate(node.alt);
        }
        processTextNodes(node); 
        i++; 
    }
},
```

The above is a method from an extension I'm writing. When run as given above I get the following in the error console

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://aatel/content/overlay.js :: processTextNodes :: line 97"  data: no]
```

In case there's any ambiguity, line 97 is:

```
node.parentNode.onmouseover = function(){ alert("AAA")};
```

If I comment out the line assigning a function to .onmouseover and uncomment the setAttribute line right above it, it works as you would expect. The big ugly opaque exception message is not helping me a lot. What am I doing wrong? Javascript isn't a strong point of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use events in a Firefox exension. Try using `addEventListener` for adding events:

```
node.parentNode.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    alert("AAA");
}, false);
```

Comment: Weird, I could swear all the examples I found online made it as if onmouseover was a property you could assign to. I guess extensions are peculiar.

Comment: Now that I think it over I remember assigning directly via a property was the legacy way of adding event handlers in javascript. It'd be prone to collisions in an extension, so it makes perfect sense that they'd disallow it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `onmouseover` setter makes certain assumptions.  For example, it assumes that the script calling it is running against a Window object.  If that's not the case, it will throw.

If your script above is in a JS component in the extension, it's not running against a Window...